# Sample data installation in preinstalled Magento on Bitnami (or other Magento installers)

Tags: php, mysql, magento, phpmyadmin

I have install Magento with Bitnami and finally, after a long struggle, everything is working now. I want to add the sample data database in phpmyadmin.

In my phpmyadmin a database called `bitnami_magento` is already present. The question is should I import the sample data in the same database already present or should I create it separately? If I add it with in the `bitnami_magento` database how shall I add it to my back-end?

Answer (score 1):

The installation of the Magento sample database must be done before installing Magento. Usual steps are as follows:

1. Create database in mysql (or phpmyadmin) with access credentials
2. Import Magento sample data into the new database
3. Install Magento which then creates its tables and includes the already present tables with data into the Magento database schema.

How you're going to do this after the fact (Magento preinstalls like Bitnami, Magento installers used via Godaddy et.al.):

1. Create another database in mysql (or phpmyadmin) with access credentials
2. Import Magento sample data into the database
3. Open app/etc/local.xml and point the database connection to the newly created database by replacing database name, login name and password.

If you import the Magento Sample Data into your current database, it will cause Magento to fail as some very important information stored during the install gets overwritten.

The new database you create will not have the Magento setups you currently have in your old database, so you will need to recreate those in the new database with the sample data.

Comment: Thanks  for your reply i'l follow your steps

Comment: Does this hold true for magento 2 with Bitnami. The Dev docs mention you can install after installation also. But someone how no clear documentation and it's crashing after given steps.

Comment: I am looking for solution with same issue in 2.2.5 mentioned by @carbonr

Answer (score 0):

if You Add sample data after magento installation don't worry just delete the app/etc/local.xml file and then again you see installation process. this time it won't take to much time b'coz your database is already there